# CodeIgniter - How to Convert timestamp into ISO_8601

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to ask about how to convert timestamp from my database to ISO_8601 format in Codeigniter

Here is my **controller**:

```
public function index()
    {
        $data['viewme'] = $this->home_model->list_data();
        $this->load->view('home', $data);
    }
```

And this is my **model**:

```
function list_data(){
    $sql   = "SELECT * FROM post";
    $query = $this->db->query();
    $data  = $query->result_array();
}
```

And this is my **view:**

```
<?php foreach($viewme as $data): ?>
  <div class=" " title="<?php echo $data['time']?>"><?php echo $data['time']?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The Problem: Time is still in timestamp format...

I have read codeigniter guide and found this

```
$format = 'DATE_ISO8601';
$waktu = time();

echo standard_date($format, $waktu);
```

But i dont know where I do to put that code into my codeigniter? any answer?

Many Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core PHP code

```
$timestamp= '7861109272';
$iso8601 = date('c', $timestamp);
```

**[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#111514)**

Comment: in View file you have to put

Comment: Like this?
<div class=" " title="<?php $timestamp= '7861109272';
$iso8601 = date('c', $timestamp); echo $data['time']?>"><?php $timestamp= '7861109272';
$iso8601 = date('c', $timestamp); echo $data['time']?></div>

Comment: If you get timestamp in `$data['time']` then you have to write `echo date('c', $data['time']);`

Comment: I'm trying<div class="" title="<?php echo date('c', $data['time']); ?>"><?php echo date('c', $data['time']); ?></div> and it didn't work
say error like this=>Severity: Notice

Message: A non well formed numeric value encountered
2013-01-01T01:33:34+01:00

Comment: can you show me what `$data['time']` will return as output? So I can help further to you.

Comment: <div><?php echo $data[time]?></div> in view display like this=> 2013-12-22 02:04:05

Comment: You have to write `echo date('c',strtotime($data['time']))`